# How to access Nexmo from an Arduino Uno?

Tags: arduino, vonage

I have a project where I have an Arduino Uno with an Ethernet shield, which needs to send messages to the Nexmo SMS API. I've done this in the past by sending serial data to a PC, which had a service running that would contact Nexmo and forward the data back to the Arduino. Unfortunately, in the latest project, I don't have access to a constantly-running PC, so I need to do a standalone system. I have experimented with Temboo and got it to work, but I've heard that once the 30-day trial runs out, it's a paid service. Obviously, I'd prefer a free service (it's a home automation project, so no client to send a bill to).

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Services like Temboo make it easier to use APIs like Nexmo from an Ardunio, but are certainly not needed.

As long as you can make an HTTP request from the Arduino (and, with the ethernet shield, you can) you can make a request to a web based API like Nexmo.

However, if you look at the [example code for making a web request with an Arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WebClient) you see that there's a fair amount of complexity. This [HttpClient](https://github.com/amcewen/HttpClient) library seems to make it a little easier, but still making a request and processing the response [takes a bit of code](https://github.com/amcewen/HttpClient/blob/master/examples/SimpleHttpExample/SimpleHttpExample.ino).

It's that complexity that Temboo is removing for you, but you can definitely do it yourself.